# What do the abbreviations "SPF" and "SPH" mean with respect to fuses? (Single line drawing for 480 V system.)

Tags: power, diagram, fuses

There are two lines connected between the transformer low voltage side and the 480 V bus, one with a fuse labeled "SPF" that connects to a GE power quality meter, another with a fuse labeled "SPH" that connects to a single winding of a transformer.

In the context of fuses, what does SPF stand for? It looks like could potentially be single-pole fuse or single pole fixed. I have no idea what SPH stands for.

Any ideas?

Comment: Note: I think these are high rupture capacity (HRC) fuses if that helps at all.

Comment: what did google tell you? Do you have part numbers?

Comment: Sorry, no part numbers. (I'm not actually on the site, and it's an old plant, so the documentation is a bit sparse.)

Comment: It means how much it protects your skin during beach season ;D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SPF and SPH are two types of "Failsafe Wirewound Resistors".  These are resistors that are designed to act as fuses, and are still common in some power supply and utility applications.  Please see [this link](http://powerelectronics.com/passive-components/fail-safe-wirewound-resistors-robust-applications/) for a description of why they are used.

The specific datasheet for the SPF/SPH parts can be found [here (pdf)](http://www.mouser.com/ds/1/414/PH-SPF-1185.pdf).

Good luck!

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe SPF for single pole fuse (individual fuse for one of three phases).

SPH may stand for "Single Phase", which would fit with your single-winding transformer.

SPF fuses seem to be "Solar Protection" which I doubt applies in this case.

Answer (score 1):

All jokes aside, SPF does stand for [Solar Protective Fuse](http://www.littelfuse.com/products/fuses/specialty-power-fuses/solar-fuses/spf.aspx)

> The SPF Solar Protection Fuse series has been specifically designed for the protection of photovoltaic (PV) systems. This family of Midget style fuses (10x38 mm) can safely protect PV (photovoltaic) modules and conductors from reverse overcurrent conditions.
>
> As PV systems have grown in size, so have the corresponding voltage requirements. This increase in system voltage has typically been intended to minimize power loss associated with long conductor runs. Standard circuit protection devices are not designed to completely protect photovoltaic panels. However, the SPF series is UL Listed to safely interrupt faulted circuits up to this demanding voltage level.
>
> Littelfuse offers various ampere ratings to match specific requirements in a variety of applications.
>
> Features and Benefits
>     1. Designed to both UL and IEC photovoltaic specifications
>     2. UL 2579 Listed 1000 VDC maximum
>     3. 1-30 A ratings available
>     4. 20,000 A Interrupting Rating

Not just LittleFuse, but Keystone and other fuse producers also use SPF for Solar PV system fuses.

Comment: It's not a solar system.

Comment: @user228546 I understand that, its jut helpful to know that SPF has multiple meanings even in the same context of high voltage systems.

Comment: Good point. Hopefully it will be helpful for someone else.